# Activate two add-ons on prestashop

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I want to activate two add-ons on prestashop but i cant activate both i get this error

> Cannot enable module blockproductsbycountry. Unable to install override: The method getProductProperties in the class Product is already overridden by the module dynamicproduct

the path

```
public_html/override/classes/Product.php

provider->isAfter1730()) { $id_product = (int) $row['id_product']; $dynamic_config = classes\models\DynamicConfig::getByProduct($id_product); if ($dynamic_config->active) { $displayed_price = classes\models\DynamicConfig::getDisplayedPrice($id_product); if ($displayed_price || $dynamic_config->display_dynamic_price) { $module->calculator->assignProductPrices($row, $displayed_price, $result); } } } return $result; } }
```

Comment: This could be because they are both trying to override the same method (getProductProperties) in the Product class, which is not allowed.

Comment: yes mr Milan i want edit code to make it accept

Comment: this is path the code

Answer (score 0):

This happens when a method of a class is overriden by both modules at the same time.

There is no automatic solution for this: you will have to check both overrides and manually merge the code back into the main Prestashop folder (**/override/classes/Product.php**).

After that you will have to remove the overridden method from the installer of both modules so that you can install/activate/deactivate them as needed without having errors.